# check for a rect in list of rects using co-ordinates in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, find, rect

If I want to see if a rect is at a given co-ordinate, how do I do this? In psuedocode, this is what I am trying to achieve...

```
xpos = 40
ypos = 40
If rect(xpos, ypos) in rects_list:
    print("There is a rect at " + xpos + ", " + ypos)
```

rects_list would look something like

```
[<rect(0, 0, 40, 40)>, <rect(40, 0, 40, 40)>, <rect(80, 0, 40, 40)>]
```

where rects are appended to the list using `rects_list.append(pygame.Rect())`

Comment: Is that about `pygame`?

Comment: *rects_list would look something like* is a bit unclear. `[<rect(0, 0, 40, 40)>, <rect(40, 0, 40, 40)>, <rect(80, 0, 40, 40)>]` by itself is not a valid python list, unless you have used some class that yields those object, which you do not mention in your question.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I append rects to the list. e.g. rects_list.append(pygame.Rect(0, 0, 40, 40)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pygame has a function called [`collidepoint(x, y)`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint).
Minimal example:

```
import pygame

l = [pygame.Rect(0, 0, 41, 41), pygame.Rect(40, 0, 40, 40), pygame.Rect(80, 0, 40, 40)]
xpos = 40
ypos = 40
if any(i.collidepoint((xpos, ypos)) for i in l):
    print(f"There is a rect at {xpos},{ypos}")
```

Result:

```
There is a rect at 40,40
```